Rotate text in docx js table
I want to rotate text so that it is written vertically in a table cell instead of horizintally. In Word you can achieve this by using these settings:

How can I achieve it using docx js? I've searched documentation and their github repository and couldn't find a solution. I've tried to use this property of a TableCell:
textDirection: TextDirection.LEFT_TO_RIGHT_TOP_TO_BOTTOM,

which I found in this demo but it didn't give any result and I assume it's not meant to rotate a text.
Part of my code:
import { TableRow, TableCell, Paragraph, TextRun, AlignmentType, VerticalAlign, TextDirection, HeightRule, convertMillimetersToTwip, WidthType } from "docx";
...
new TableCell({
                children: [
                    new Paragraph({
                        children: [
                            new TextRun({
                                text: `Some text here`,
                                size: 28,
                            })
                        ],
                        alignment: AlignmentType.CENTER,
                    })
                ],
                textDirection: TextDirection.LEFT_TO_RIGHT_TOP_TO_BOTTOM,
                width: {
                    size: convertMillimetersToTwip(10),
                    type: WidthType.DXA,
                },
                rowSpan: 16,
                verticalAlign: VerticalAlign.CENTER,
            }),


Isn't left to right top to bottom the normal way that text is laid out in English at least? Sounds like you want bottom to top and left to right.

Yes, I want it vertical bottom to top

Have you tried setting TextDirection to what you want rather than the standard way which you've got at the moment?

Of course. There is only one additional option: TOP_TO_BOTTOM_RIGHT_TO_LEFT
